# ms access ODBC returns empty string C#

Tags: unity-game-engine

There is Database .mdb, connected with ODBC in Unity3d (Mono.net) on Windows 8. It connects successfully, but when i tried to get data from first row it returns only numerical value (int), all string parameters are empty.

```
string _connectionstring = @"Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2 ANSI Driver};Dsn=MS Access Database;uid=Admin";

        OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(_connectionstring);
        conn.Open();

        string sql_query = "SELECT Name, Description, Type FROM Items WHERE ID = ?";
        OdbcCommand oCmd = new OdbcCommand(sql_query, conn);
        oCmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", OdbcType.Int).Value = 1;

        oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", OdbcType.VarChar);
        OdbcDataReader reader = oCmd.ExecuteReader();

        var Name = "";
        string Decrpt = "";
        int Type = 0;

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Name = reader.GetString(0);
            Decrpt = reader["Description"].ToString();

            Type = (int)reader["Type"];
            Debug.Log("Name is: " + Name.ToString() + "   Descrpt: "  + Decrpt + "  Type is: " + Type.ToString());
        }
```

And im getting this log:

```
Name is:    Descrpt:   Type is: 1
```

Only type returns correct value

row in database is:

```
ID  Name        Description                 Type
1   First Item  Description of first Item   1
```

and i also tried other variations of getting data:

```
Convert.ToString(reader["Name"])
(string)reader["Description"]
reader.GetValue(0)
```

and others, and there is always empty string.

What should i do to get my string data?

Comment: Are you sure your reader is returned the correct data? You command parameters don't look right. Should there be two parameters?

Comment: Where it should be two parameters? I think it returns right because type value is correct, and if i try to get ID it returns correct too, but two strings always empty